# How to convert MS Word HTML document to clean XHTML inline style?

Tags: java, css, ms-word, html-parsing, jsoup

I have a problem with an internal CSS. Jsoup doesn't parse `@font-face` or similar. How can I clean a MS Word HTML document?

Comment: While Jsoup uses CSS selectors to select HTML elements, it's not a CSS parser, but a pure HTML parser.

Comment: This has been answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67964/what-is-the-best-free-way-to-clean-up-word-html

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience.

We had to parse  word documents too, but the complicated word content prevented us. We had a rich text editor where it allowed to past content from word into it and then we would submit that content to the server to parse it via jsoup.

It may not solve your problem, but just my 2 cents..